# Unexpected Gamma in output (Bug?)

Tags: math-mode, breqn

I've got one of the weirdest results I ever saw. When inputting the following code, the output was not just the normal "implies" sign (⇒), but had a capital greek Gamma (Γ) in front of it. So: Γ⇒

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\implies$
\end{document}
```

I suspect the reason for this is the `\usepackage{breqn}`. 
I am curious to get an explanation however!

And if someone has a solution other than using different packages, that would be great to hear as well

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Load `breqn` *after* `amsmath`.

Comment: Loading `breqn` before `amsmath` leads to compilation errors

Comment: @Bernard, thanks for welcoming! Why does it lead to error, do you guys know that?

Comment: `breqn` is not the most stable package.

Comment: I had an error message about `\dfrac, \tfrac` already defined, so I thought it was possibly linked to this, and just tried swapping the loading order.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'd like to disagree.  `breqn` is pretty stable, albeit not very compatible.  One definitely has to study the manual throughly before using.

Comment: @HenriMenke Point taken.  Compatibility is a much better descriptor of the issue.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Bernard Would you like to add an answer or should we close it as solved in comments?

Comment: @CarLaTeX: In my opinion it can be  closed as solved in comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was only a wrong order of loading packages, solved in comments.